# How can i get textView in the scrolledWindow?

Tags: ruby, gtk

i am using ruby-gtk. There is a notebook in my application. I added textView to scrolledWindow. I want to get textView buffer. My some code

```
editor = Textview.new
swin = Gtk::ScrolledWindow.new
tab = Gtk::Notebook.new
swin.add(editor)
tab.append_page(swin, Gtk::Label.new("Tab")
tab.get_nth_page(current_page).buffer # wrong because its contain is a scrolledWindow
```

How can i get editor buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [`GtkScrolledWindow`](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3AScrolledWindow) *is a* `GtkBin`, you can make use of [`child`](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3ABin#child) method to get the widget added as the child. In your case it should return `GtkTextView`. Try something on the lines of:

```
tab.get_nth_page(current_page).child.buffer
```

Hope this helps!